# An appropriate adjective

Tags: word-choice, expressions, adjectives, sentence

> I am writing a report and it should tell all the stakeholders that
>   "the target for all product categories, including Over Payments to
>   customers has either been met or exceeded (by a very small amount).

I thought of barely, narrowly- **negative connotations.**

> Can I end the sentence with an adjective that carries the messsage
>   that though we have exceeeded the target, it's by a minor number.

Note- We are **only** supposed to meet the target, over-doing is not a necessity but we somehow exceeded the target.

Comment: I am unclear as to what you are asking. Why can't you say *...have been exceeded by a very small amount* ?

Comment: If it bothers you, why not just forget the totally unnecessary "exceeded" bit entirely? That might make it easier for you to see/correct the verb plurality issue - you need either ***targets ... have*** or ***target ... has** been met*.

Answer (score 4):

I understand why "barely" might have slightly negative connotations, but I don't feel "narrowly" does.

In any case, words for "by a little" include:

> **slightly** (adv.): to a small degree; not considerably.
>
> **marginally** (adv.): to only a limited extent; slightly.

Definitions by Google dictionary.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that *narrowly exceeded* has no negative connotation and for *slightly* which is even simpler and very clear. I might prefer those over *marginally*, just because *margin, marginal* have special meanings within finance.

Comment: marginally, what else?

Answer (score 0):

If the amount that the targets have been exceeded by is extremely minor, to the point of being unimportant, I would go with simply "all targets have been met," which continues to be true even if some targets have actually been exceeded.

If any of the targets had been exceeded by a significant amount, you would go with "met or exceeded," (but this is not the case).

The point is that you're trying to communicate with your stakeholders, and the important message is that targets have been met.  The excess is of such a small magnitude that it only confuses the issue to inform them of it.